# Simulate click with javascript to click on banner

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I want to simulate click (js) to banner code (random linked banners).

```
function simulateClicks(); 

echo bannerCode;
```

How can this be done?

details :

When user open website user automatic click on x,y diagrams definied in function simulateClicks(); or direct on

definied bannerCode; - bannerCode; is full code of random linked banners centered on site. (400x200). Example:

pokit.org/get/img/c183f22c67d2c7827a93c2bd442f288a.jpg When user open this question automatic opening my profile

(auto click on my linked profile name). In my case that is random banner linked to locations, and i definied it as

bannerCode;

mission : 
Only simulate click with javascript on banner.. that's all I need.

Comment: Can you show an example of rendered HTML code ? Do the banners have a specific id or class ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This looks like tricking the users.

Comment: Are you looking for something like http://api.jquery.com/trigger/ ?

Comment: i cant even think of a way i can edit your question.

Comment: @RobSchmuecker He probably just wants to make them an offer they can't refuse. Regardless, most browsers prevent JS-triggered clicks from doing a whole bunch of things that are not prevented for native clicks.

Comment: banner have ID but link is on 2x iframe. banner is on iframe 1.. iframe 1 in iframe 2 :)

Answer (score 2):

If you know how to select your "banner" with a css-selector, you can just "trigger" it with jquerys `.trigger()`

```
$("#the_id_of_the_banner").trigger('click');
```